# React Not Instantiating New Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

So I have a react component, which renders an anchor differently depending on where the URL points. Basically, there is a file on the server which could be a normal file, or it could be a text file containing a URL. If it contains a normal file, I want the href to be the location of the file. If it is a text with a URL inside, I want it to point to that URL. I have a list of these files that I want to display, and the list is sometimes populated with completely different entries depending on state and a whole bunch of other stuff. So essentially the logic is like this:

```
listOfFiles.map((file, index) => {
    return (
           <FileAnchor
            file={file}
            methodToCheckFileType={theMethodToCheckFileType}
           />
    );
});

class FileAnchor extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            file: props.file,
            url: null
        }

        this.methodToCheckFileType = props.methodToCheckFileType;
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.methodToCheckFileType(this.state.file)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                url: response.url
            });
        })
    }

    render(){
        return this.state.url !== null && (
            <a href={this.state.url}>{this.state.file.filename</a>
        );
    }
}

export default FileAnchor;
```

It works great when the first list is loaded. Everything works as expected. However, when the list is emptied and repopulated with different files, the entries from the first list are not removed. I've debugged this, and the `listOfFiles` variable contains all of the new files, and none of the old. The props being sent to `FileAnchor` are all of the new files. However the constructor for `FileAnchor` is not being called for the first however many entries there were in the first list. If there were 4 entries in the first list, and 6 entries in the next list. The first four will be from the first list, and the last two will be the last two from the second list.

So basically, the FileAnchor components are being reused? I can't imagine why this is the case when different props are being sent to them. Can anyone help shed some light on this? I feel like it's probably some basic tenet of how ReactJS works that I haven't grasped. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to the life cycle method `componentDidMount()` only being called once per component instance. I have a feeling in this case that react will try to re-use component instances where possible, which would mean `componentDidMount()` isn't called when your `listOfFiles` is emptied/repopulated in a single render cycle.

Try adding the following method to your component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    // If the incoming file prop doesn't match the current file
    // prop of this component instance, update internal state via
    // setState to trigger a re-render, and call methodToCheckFileType()
    // as in your componentDidMount() method
    if(nextProps.file !== this.props.file) {

    this.setState({ file : nextProps.file })         

    this.methodToCheckFileType(nextProps.file)
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({
            url: response.url
        });
    })
    }
 }
```

Comment: This fixed my problem! Thanks so much, I was pulling my hair out trying to work out why it wasn't updating.